# PHPMyadmin xampp error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm desperately trying to get phpmyadmin access on xampp for linux 1.8.0  for ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I know this is a common problem, but I have tried many threads across the web, and I am still stuck getting it going.

Xampp seems to be running ok, localhost start page good, including link to phpmyadmin in the sidebar. When I follow that link I get a 403 error:

> Access forbidden!
>
> New XAMPP security concept:
>
> Access to the requested directory is only available from the local
>   network.
>
> This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 403
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.2 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4

I have tried numerous things, including amending httpd-xampp.conf, the relevant bits of which now look like: http://pastebin.com/J4f4tNVs

my /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php looks like: http://pastebin.com/5PZPXK5s

Following other instructions I changed ownership of /lampp with:

```
chown -Rv nobody:root ./lampp/*
```

Please help me!

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I've found a solution here: http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=50902&p=196185#p196185

Edit /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf and adding **Require all granted** line at bottom of block `<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">` to have the following code:

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
  AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks. This problem broke me, so I moved on to LAMP to meet a deadline. I'll be back if I try XAMPP again.

Comment: This needs to be marked as the answer, because that's exactly what it is!