# Error 403 as I try to open phpmyadmin. What do I do to correct it?

Tags: php, linux, phpmyadmin, xampp

As I try open `localhost/phpmyadmin/` I get the following error :

```
Access forbidden!

New XAMPP security concept:

Access to the requested directory is only available from the local network.

This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403
```

Why is that ? I opened the `httpd-xampp.conf` file but I don't know what to do in that.

This is the complete `httpd-xampp.conf` file :

```
<IfDefine PHP4>
LoadModule php4_module        modules/libphp4.so
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine PHP5>
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
</IfDefine>
# Disabled in XAMPP 1.8.0-beta2 because of current incompatibilities with Apache 2.4
# LoadModule perl_module        modules/mod_perl.so


Alias /phpmyadmin "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin"
Alias /phpsqliteadmin "/opt/lampp/phpsqliteadmin"

# since XAMPP 1.4.3
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpsqliteadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

# since LAMPP 1.0RC1
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4

XBitHack on

# since 0.9.8 we've mod_perl
<IfModule mod_perl.c>
    AddHandler perl-script .pl
    PerlHandler ModPerl::PerlRunPrefork
    PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
    PerlSendHeader On
</IfModule>

# demo for mod_perl responsehandler
#PerlModule Apache::CurrentTime
#<Location /time>
#      SetHandler modperl
#      PerlResponseHandler Apache::CurrentTime
#</Location>

# AcceptMutex sysvsem is default but on some systems we need this
# thanks to jeff ort for this hint
#AcceptMutex flock
#LockFile /opt/lampp/logs/accept.lock

# this makes mod_dbd happy - oswald, 02aug06
# mod_dbd doesn't work in Apache 2.2.3: getting always heaps of "glibc detected *** corrupted double-linked list" on shutdown - oswald, 10sep06
#DBDriver sqlite3

#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
        fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
        fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16

    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: try solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630412/phpmyadmin-xampp-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this section is your problem, your IP address / IP range mustn't be in the list of allowed IPs

```
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    # The line below this comment!
    Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
        fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
        fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16

    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

If this is a development environment then the following would suffice:

```
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all

    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Otherwise, just add your IP range to the allowed section :)

Edit: I should put the answer from the comments here so people can see it easier:

> "Alright, try adding Require all granted on the line after the Allow
>   from all line in the  section."

Comment: As I remove the section you mentioned,I cannot even access the `localhost` page !

Comment: Can you show me what you put exactly? And what happens when you try access it?

Comment: `<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all

 ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>`

Comment: It's the same as you mentioned !

Comment: and I get the same message as I was getting earlier

Comment: Can you try removing the whole `LocationMatch` block?

Comment: Alright, try adding `Require all granted` on the line after the `Allow from all` line in the `<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">` section.