# phpmyadmin is missing from xampp

Tags: php, mysql, windows, xampp

Recently, I installed xampp on windows 10, and after starting MySQL, I try to hit the "Admin" button, and it opens a web page at:

```
Not Found

HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.
```

When I look in the htdocs directory, the phpmyadmin directory is there, but it is empty.  Could anybody tell me, why can I not do have any MySQL admin with the latest install of XAMP?  Here is the last part of my mysql_error.log file:

```
2016-05-31 14:55:54 3852 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2016-05-31 14:55:54 11364 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2016-05-31 14:55:54 3852 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2016-05-31 14:55:55 3852 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1835057
2016-05-31 14:55:55 3852 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

2016-05-31 14:59:23 1ec0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-05-31 14:59:24 7872 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-05-31 14:59:24 7872 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-05-31 14:59:24 7872 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-05-31 14:59:24 7872 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-05-31 14:59:24 7872 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-05-31 14:59:24 7872 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2016-05-31 14:59:24 7872 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-05-31 14:59:24 7872 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-05-31 14:59:24 7872 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-05-31 14:59:24 7872 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-05-31 14:59:24 7872 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-05-31 14:59:24 7872 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.28-76.1 started; log sequence number 1835057
2016-05-31 14:59:24 11404 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-05-31 14:59:24 7872 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-05-31 14:59:24 7872 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-05-31 14:59:24 7872 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.13-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

**UPDATE:**

After installing, the phpadmin directory in htdocs is empty.  Also, I have checked out these posts but still haven't found a solution: [I can not access phpMyAdmin on XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255567/i-can-not-access-phpmyadmin-on-xampp) and [PHPMyadmin xampp error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630412/phpmyadmin-xampp-error?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to use the right port, because I had modified it from the default 80 for Apache:

http://localhost:56789/phpmyadmin/